# Immer - Get error with async function in produce

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, immer.js

I'm trying to create an asynchronous produce with immer but I get an error when I call this async function :

This my code :

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import produce from 'immer';

const mainReducer = produce(async (draft, { type, payload }: { type: string; payload: any }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'foo': {
            draft = await myAsyncFn(payload);
        }
    }
});

const reducers = {
    main: mainReducer,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers);

export const mainStore = createStore(rootReducer);
```

This is the output : `Error: [Immer] produce can only be called on things that are draftable: plain objects, arrays, Map, Set or classes that are marked with '[immerable]: true'. Got '[object Promise]'`

Why doesn't it work ? (I thought It's was possible : https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/async)

What does it mean by `classes that are marked with '[immerable]` ?

Comment: Presumably you mean: `produce(draft, async ({ type, payload }: { type: string; payload: any }) => { ... })`?

Comment: No ... @James .. unfortunely

Comment: I'll give up this library

Answer (score 2):

While Immer does appear to let you write async logic inside of `produce`, [**you must never write async logic in a Redux reducer**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects).

Having said that, the specific error here is because by default, Immer only knows how to update plain JS objects and arrays.  In order to update a class instance or similar, [you have to add a special `immerable` symbol to that class type](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/complex-objects).

Note that you *should* be using Immer with Redux, but [as part of our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which has Immer built into its `createSlice` API.

Answer (score -2):

Might not be so relevant but I got this error using redux-toolkit. The createSlice() method was working well until I changed the type of the state to a generic typescript type. Then it started throwing the mentioned error.

```js
import { AsyncState } from "./AsyncState";

export class SliceState<T> {
  constructor(initialState: T) {
    this.data = initialState;
    this.status = new AsyncState();
  }
  status: AsyncState;
  data: T;
}
```

Additional error information: [Immer] produce can only be called on things that are draftable: plain objects, arrays, Map, Set or classes that are marked with '[immerable]: true'. Got '[object Object]'